# What happens when a partition in a DynamoDB table with a local secondary index exceeds capacity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having a bit of trouble reconciling documentation on how DynamoDB behaves when a partition exceeds capacity of 10GB when there is a local secondary index.

In [this article about how adaptive capacity makes many DynamoDB best practices / constraints obsolete](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/), it is said that

> DynamoDB **splits partitions by sort key** if the collection size grows bigger than 10 GB.

But, in [this article about adaptive capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-partitions-adaptive)

> Adaptive capacity **will not split item collections across multiple partitions** of the table when there is a local secondary index on the table.

I know the information in these two articles aren't mutually exclusive, but it seems weird that the first article wouldn't at least mention the tremendous downside of having a local secondary index if that were the case.

So, what exactly happens when a partition exceeds capacity with a local secondary index? Does it just throttle the DynamoDB table since it can't split the partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all please feel free to provide feedback directly on any documentation page which you feel is missing information, that will cut a ticket internally to the team responsible.

To answer your question, when a partition with an LSI grows to 10GB in size you will begin to receive `ItemCollectionSizeLimitExceededException` which will not allow you to add further data to that partition, you will also be blocked from updating items if the size of the item grows from the update. You will be allowed to delete and read items.

More information can be found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.ItemCollections.SizeLimit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will definitely give feedback on the first article to include the caveat of tables with LSI's. This seems like just another reason for why it simply doesn't make sense to use LSI over GSI. I'm curious, what is the reason why only tables with LSI can't split partitions, but tables without can? Is it because partition splitting happens on the sort key, and having multiple sort keys would make that not feasible?

Comment: Thanks for providing feedback, great appreciated. 

As for LSI vs GSI, only use LSI if you need strong consistency and you are aware of the caveats.

LSI is tightly coupled with the base partition, splitting on the SK would no longer provide that tight coupling, as it would now become a GSI essentially and not be able to provide strong consistency.